# Socket programming: 302 Found

Tags: java, sockets

Im trying to connect to www.google.com using socket but the result is:

HTTP/1.0 302 Found
Location: http://www.google.com.ph/
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Here's my Java test code:

```
    Socket sock = new Socket();  
    try {
        sock.connect(new InetSocketAddress("www.google.com", 80));
        InputStream in = sock.getInputStream();
        OutputStream out = sock.getOutputStream();

        out.write(new String("GET /\r\n").getBytes());

        byte[] readBuffer = new byte[4096];
        while(true) {
            int readSize = in.read(readBuffer);
            if(readSize < 1) break;
            System.out.println(new String(readBuffer, 0, readSize));
        }

        sock.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {

    }
```

What's wrong with this? Btw, I need to achieve this using only sockets. tnx

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Then why does it says 302 Found? This is a test for a project I'm making in which I have to get some values displayed on a webpage and integrate it with my project.

Comment: 302 is an HTTP code for redirection. It's not an error, you just need to make the program follow the redirection.

Comment: At the end of the response there is this:

<H1>302 Moved</H1>  
The document has moved  
<A HREF="http://www.google.com.ph/">here</A>.  
</BODY></HTML>  

so it means the redirections url is http://www.google.com.ph but when I connect to this my program terminated without the resulting response

Comment: I displayed the exception message and it's unknownHostException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`www.google.com` will redirect you based on your IP's location. In your case, in the Philippines, you will be redirected to `www.google.com.ph`. Try to request that domain directly instead.

```
Socket sock = new Socket();  
try {
    sock.connect(new InetSocketAddress("www.google.com.ph", 80));
    InputStream in = sock.getInputStream();
    OutputStream out = sock.getOutputStream();

    out.write(new String("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.google.com.ph\r\n\r\n").getBytes());

    byte[] readBuffer = new byte[4096];
    while(true) {
        int readSize = in.read(readBuffer);
        if(readSize < 1) break;
        System.out.println(new String(readBuffer, 0, readSize));
    }

    sock.close();
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You need to specify the HTTP version (in this case 1.1) and along with that, the Host header field (required by that version).

Your request doesn't specify the version, so it used 1.0.

Comment: Yes, Im in the Phil. but still the same result..302 not found
and when i used a browser it doesn't redirect me to google.com.ph

Comment: How about adding `http://`? It doesn't redirect you probably because of the cookies you have in your browser.

Comment: yep, already added that but i get java.net.UnknownHostException: http://`www.google.com

Comment: Please see my answer, I made an explanation. :)

Comment: @Ruel This is not a perfect answer, try to see `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10329779/httpresponse-code-302`

Answer (score 0):

When you go to google.com in a browser does it redirect to something like google.ca?

I say this because http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302 suggests that google.com gets redirected.