# HttpURLConnection not able to read 302 Response code

Tags: java, http-status-code-302, httpconnection

I am trying to download a file through code and it is working if the file is found. But if the Link returns a 302 code, I am getting a connection timeout through code. It is working fine in browser.

Can someone help me out where I am going wrong?

My code is given below:

```
private static void downloadFile(String fileUrl, String fileName) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(fileUrl);

            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setConnectTimeout(60000);
            connection.setReadTimeout(60000);
            connection.connect();

            int code = connection.getResponseCode();
            String message = connection.getResponseMessage();
            System.out.println(code + "-" + message);

            if (code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                try (BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
                        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileName)) {
                    byte dataBuffer[] = new byte[1024];
                    int bytesRead;
                    while ((bytesRead = in.read(dataBuffer, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
                        fileOutputStream.write(dataBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                throw new Exception("Invalid Response Code: " + code + ", Response Message: " + message);
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
        }
    }
```

Working URL(200): https://archives.nseindia.com/content/historical/DERIVATIVES/2022/SEP/fo16SEP2022bhav.csv.zip

Timeout URL(302): https://archives.nseindia.com/content/historical/DERIVATIVES/2022/SEP/fo17SEP2022bhav.csv.zip

Comment: It seems that you need to use the URL given back from the header each time you get a `302 response` to download the file [HttpResponse code 302](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10329779/httpresponse-code-302#:~:text=An%20HTTP%20302%20is%20a,You%20need%20to%20handle%20it.&text=You%20need%20to%20extract%20the,%22%20to%20do%20this).

Comment: @MohamadGhaithAlzin I am not able to read the response. I am getting ```java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out``` on ```connection.getResponseCode();```

Answer (score 1):

A setting

**connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true); // follow response codes 3xx**

```
connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(fileUrl).openConnection();
connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true); // follow response codes 3xx
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setConnectTimeout(60000);
            connection.setReadTimeout(60000);
connection.connect();
```

Comment: The default value is already set to true which comes from followRedirects. Turning it off has solved my problem. I am getting 302 response code after that. Thanks.